# Cells "grown in LB broth to an OD600nm"

Tags: cell-culture

> Cells "grown in LB broth to an OD600nm"

What does the OD stand for in this?

Comment: Just a google search would have fetched you the answer.

Comment: This phrase in isolation has no meaning, because the value itself is missing: "to OD of **X** at 600 nm".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**OD** = **O**ptical **D**ensity

As you grow cells in broth, the broth becomes cloudy. The more cells there are, the cloudier it is. After you grow your cells for a while, you can measure their progress by shining a light through your sample. The more light your cell culture absorbs (higher absorbance is equivalent to higher OD) the more cells there are in it.